# Oracle Sql Not Giving Result: Count Json Objects Inside Json Array

Tags: sql, json, oracle12c

I have a table named `DATA` with a JSON column named `RJSON` with the following content:

```
{
  "TEST":"ABCD",
  "PROPERTIES":{
         "RESULT":[ 
                   {"f":["APPLES","ORANGES","GRAPE"]},
                   {"f":["APPLES","GRAPE"]},
                   {"f":["APPLES","ORANGES"]}]
      }
}
```

I want output:

```
APPLES: 3
ORANGES:2
GRAPES: 2
```

I want to know how to do this in SQL

What I have done:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM DATA o,
        JSON_TABLE ( o.RJSON,'$.PROPERTIES.RESULTS[*]'
            COLUMNS (f VARCHAR2 ( 1000 CHAR ) PATH '$.f'
            )
        ) t
WHERE 1=1;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the ALL CAPS (shouting), and show what you have so far.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @jarlh: I am using oracle

Comment: From your tag it seems you're using 11g. `JSON_TABLE` is only available from Oracle 12c. You should update your Oracle version to be able to use it.